# Clipboard replacements (Ditto, ClipX) stopped working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, clipboard, ditto

Over the past few days, I've noticed that the clipboard replacement application I use (Ditto) isn't working any more. Specifically, it isn't copying items to its list. It still shows the history of items copies before, but doesn't add any new items. I am still able to paste past items, so the program is still functional.

It will work for a while after quitting and restarting the program, but then it will soon stop  getting new items again.

I've tried using ClipX, another clipboard replacement app, and that doesn't get new items either. This leads me to think this is a Windows problem.
I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Is anyone else having this problem? Any ideas on what might be causing it?

**Update:** I've found that if I Disconnect from the clipboard, then Connect to clipboard again, then it works for a while, but stops collecting items again after 15 mins.

Comment: Have you been copying stuff from an elevated process (i.e. run as Administrator ones)?

Comment: Ditto, Arsclip, and ClipBoard Manager Gadget works fine here.

Comment: @billc.cn: No, I've been copying stuff from regular processes. Could that be part of the issue? It's been working for months before it no longer holds copied items in its clipboard.

Comment: What are your UAC settings? Did you try to switch off UAC for some time to see what happens then?

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin: My UAC settings are pretty locked down, as this is a work computer. I do have the Administrator password, and am able to elevate permissions when I need to.

Comment: **Update**: For some reason, this problem went away on its own. I'm able to use Ditto as it used to work, collecting everything that I copy. This is kind of frustrating, as it doesn't address the original issue.

Comment: I think it would be good to find a way to move toward closing this question - either by re-focusing the original question on just ClipX (if the problem still exists there, where more troubleshooting can be done) or by posting some troubleshooting steps for ditto as an answer - for example, isolating the problem to a specific version number of ditto (or trying a beta / dev version if available). Also, this page has details on collecting debug log info which could help in finding a useful answer: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ditto-cp/wiki/Debug%20Logging

Comment: I've had this problem with every clipboard manager utility I've ever used on Windows.  In my case, I've always suspected that the problem is related to my frequent use of Remote Desktop, which hooks the clipboard and may interfere with the clipboard manager software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answerer left an update in the comments:

> Update: For some reason, this problem went away on its own. I'm able to use Ditto as it used to work, collecting everything that I copy. This is kind of frustrating, as it doesn't address the original issue. – Bassam Mar 1 at 18:03

Here are some suggestions if you might experience this problem as well:

1. Try to run with elevated permissions and a less locked down UAC.
2. Update your Windows and software.
3. Create a new user profile to see whether it happens there.
4. Remove automatically starting entries, as another start-up program might perhaps interfere...

Comment: Since teh problem fixed itself, and I have no way of diagnosing a problem that no longer happens, I'm marking this answer as the accepted answer, since it has good general suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Ditto's option dialog, `General` tab, use the `Compact and Repair Database` option, and also try limiting the number of entries stored (`Maximum Number of Saved Copies`) - I use 5000.

The combination of those two options for me keeps it pretty stable.

There's also a `Ensure Ditto is always connected to the clipboard` option, which I think is on by default, but is worth checking.